# GJR-GARCH Model In R

Tags: volatility, trading, programming, r, garch

Any idea how to estimate GJR-GARCH models in R? Is there any particular library like fGarch that supports such models?

Comment: `library(sos); ???GJR` suggests that the `rugarch` package can fit this model.

Comment: Please note that, according to our [faq](http://quant.stackexchange.com/faq), such questions are off-topic and should be directed to [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Tal, I think it's borderline. We have **econometrics** explicitly stated in the FAQ as OK, so I doubt it's that off. Especially, since we have a number of similar questions with a long history on the site and ARCH modelling is quite common in quant finance.

Comment: @KarolPiczak except that this question is not asking about how to apply GJR-GARCH, just for some software help, which is explicitly identified in the FAQ as off-topic.  To clarify, econometrics questions that ask about a specific finance problem are on-topic, questions purely about the software are off-topic.

Comment: @Tal OK. Got it.

Answer (score 8):

You can have a look at `rgarch`. It's quite versatile. From what I remember, you have to get it explicitly from R-Forge, as it's not available from CRAN.

See the [rgarch website](http://rgarch.r-forge.r-project.org/index.html) for more details.

Last time I checked, usage was something like this:

```
spec.gjrGARCH = ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="gjrGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)), mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1,1), include.mean=TRUE), distribution.model="std")
gjrGARCH <- ugarchfit(data, spec=spec.gjrGARCH)
```

From what I see, it has been recently split into uni- and multivariate packages, so you would need to verify the syntax and install `rugarch`.

Comment: `rugarch` really is fantastic.

Answer (score 4):

CRAN has a few:

- [bayesGARCH](http://cran.rproject.org/web/packages/bayesGARCH/index.html)
- [gogarch](http://cran.rproject.org/web/packages/gogarch/index.html)
- [ccgarch](http://cran.rproject.org/web/packages/ccgarch/index.html)