# GJR-GARCH model using garchFit function

Tags: garch, value-at-risk, forecasting

I'm trying to use the `garchFit` function [described here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fGarch/versions/3042.83.1/topics/garchFit) in order to define a GJR-GARCH model to estimate volatility and then forecast VaR.

I tried using `ugarchspec` to estimate the model but it didn't work, so I was wondering if it was possible to estimate it using the `garchFit` function I linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ugarchspec()` function is part of the `rugarch`-package which works with the `rugarch` set of functions. `rugrach` does support GJR-GARCH. The `fGarch`-package works differently, you can call `garchFit()` directly. It seems to me that `fGarch` does *not* support any other GARCH specification than regular GARCH or APARCH, as suggested by this error message:

```
> garchFit(~ gjrgarch(1,1), data = x.vec, trace = FALSE)
Error in .garchInitSeries(formula.mean = formula.mean, formula.var = formula.var,  : 
  formula.var must be one of: garch, aparch
```

[This question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/3477/848) and the overview given by `library(sos); ???gjr` suggest that the authors of `fGarch` mention GJR-GARCH but didn't implement it (yet).